# Mail send function not getting called from .php Customer Form

Tags: php, forms, email

I am new to PHP coding. I have created a Customer form, followed by send e-mail function. When a Customer submits data (including E-Mail and password) he should receive a confirmation e-mail with User ID (same as entered E-Mail Id) and entered Password.
At this moment, with my current code, when a Customer submits the form, database gets updated, but no e-mail is send to the user. Can anyone point out what needs to be changed to ensure that send e-mail function works correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Registration Desk</title>

    </head>
    <body>   
        <div  class="form">
            <form id="contactform" action="reg_submit.php" method="post"> 
                <p class="contact"><label for="name">Name</label></p> 
                <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="First and last name" required=""   tabindex="1" type="text"> 

                <p class="contact"><label for="add">Address</label></p> 
                <textarea id="add" name="add"  style="width:85%; height:60%; margin-top:1%" required=""></textarea> 

                <fieldset>
                    <label>Birthday</label>
                    <input type="date"   name="dob" value="yyyy-mm-dd" required="">
                </fieldset>



                <label>I am</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>


                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" >Male &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female




                <p class="contact"><label for="email">Email</label></p> 
                <input id="email" name="email" class="field" placeholder="Please enter a valid emailid" required="" type="email">


                <p class="contact"><label for="password">Create a password</label></p> 
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required=""> 
                <p class="contact"><label for="repassword">Confirm your password</label></p> 
                <input type="password" id="repassword" name="repassword" required=""> 


                <br><br>

                <p class="contact"><label for="phone">Mobile phone</label></p> 
                <input id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone number" required="" type="text"> <br>
                <input class="buttom" name="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Sign me up!" type="submit">      
            </form> 
        </div>      
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
error_reporting( 0);
$connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","wbtecqoj_saltee","webuildtec1","wbtecqoj_salteegroup");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();   
}


if( $_POST["password"]!= $_POST["repassword"])
{
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    alert("password miss matched!!!.");
    history.back();


    </script>

<?php

}
if($_POST["name"]  &&  $_POST["add"]  &&  $_POST["phone"] &&  $_POST["email"] &&  $_POST["password"] &&  $_POST["dob"]  ) 
{
    $insert="INSERT INTO `db`.`new_user` (`id`, `name`, `add`, `contact`, `email`, `pass`, `dob`, `gender`,`code`) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[add]', '$_POST[phone]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[password]',  '$_POST[dob]', '$_POST[sex]', 'SAL1000000')";

    if(!mysqli_query($connect,$insert))
    {
        echo die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connect));
    }
    else
    {

        $to=$_POST['email'];
        $from= "admin@wbtec.in";
        $subject="Welcome to xyz Group";


        $message="Welcome " . $_POST['name'] . "Dear Customer,
Your  Card Number is    " .$Ccode.$cookieId. " User id -" . $_POST['email'] . "Your Password -" . $_POST['password']. 
"Thanking You,
Customer Care,";
        $header = "From" .$from;

        if(isset($_POST['btnSend']))
        {
            $res = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
            if($res)
            {
                echo 'Message send';
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'msg not send';
            }
        }

}}
mysqli_close($connect);
?>
```

Comment: u cant send mail from localhost...if u want send mail from local then u have to use php mailer

Comment: Is the webserver and the mailserver the same machine?

Comment: I am using Bigrock as my webhost and this is what the site says -http://manage.bigrock.com/kb/servlet/KBServlet/faq1311.html with regards to SMTP server settings - hope this helps.

Comment: If you have another email account, e.g. at GMAIL you could try to set the following parameters: `$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; $mail->SMTPAuth = true; $mail->Username = "your GMAIL email"; $mail->Password = "your GMAIL password";` just for testing, if the mail is sent at all. If using your Bigrock mail server, you have to have an mail account there.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the

```
   if(isset($_POST['btnSend']))
    {
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prince, that was indeed a typo error. I have removed the same, yet i get the error -'msg not send'  :(

Comment: use your domain smtp server name instead of localhost

Answer (score 2):

You are checking for

```
if(isset($_POST['btnSend']))
```

But your form doesn't contain an input named btnSend, you should be able to remove that if statement altogether

Answer (score 0):

u have to download php mailer library which have to files 
[PHP mailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

`class.phpmailer.php` and other  `class.smtp.php` then add this file at same directory which have php code which is shown below..

```
<?PHP
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        // process the form here

    $subject = "This is subject testing1";
    $mail = new PHPMailer();    
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML    
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port 
    //$mail->Username   = "gmailusername";                    // GMAIL username
    //$mail->Password   = "password";                                           // GMAIL password   
    $mail->From       = 'email id';
    $mail->FromName   = "FrontName";
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->Body       = "this is html body";           //HTML Body
    $emailId='email id';
    $emails  = explode(",",$emailId);
    foreach($emails as $email)
           $mail->AddAddress($email);

    if($mail->Send()){
        echo "Message sent successfully";
    }else{
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name='button1'value="sent mail" />
</form>
```

Comment: @ Thanks Mayur - I have made the changes - yet get the same error. By the way, I have mentioned server name as "localhost" since my web host mentions it specificaally. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use PHPMailer from
http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

With the PHPMailer class you can specify the outgoing SMTP server and authenticate with it properly. Here is an example how I used it:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");

class Mailer
{
    function send($email, $subject, $body, $attachment1)
    {
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP();                                   // send via SMTP
        $mail->Host     = "mail.xyz.com"; // your SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "authname";  // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "authpassword"; // SMTP password

        $mail->From     = "info@xyz.com";
        $mail->FromName = "info@xyz.com";
        $mail->AddAddress($email); 

        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                              // set word wrap
        if ($attachment1 != "") {
            $mail->AddAttachment($attachment1);      // attachment1
        }
        $mail->IsHTML(false);                               // send as HTML

        $mail->Subject  =  $subject;
        $mail->Body     =  $body;

        if(!$mail->Send())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: @ rawdog - thanks for ur suggestion -I am going to try this now and share this feedback. Cheers!

Comment: The both answers with removing the `if(isset($_POST['btnSend']))` are correct, too! My suggestion is for making the sending process more stable and safe.